# Searching a String for stop words

Tags: java, string, eclipse

I am trying to search my string "zach" for the stop words THE", "BE", "TO", "OF", "AND", "A", "IN", "THAT", "I", "IT", "ON", "IN", "BUT", "IS", "WITH".

I am not sure if the string search method will work or if there is a better way to do this.

```
package zk;

public class Class 
{

    public boolean isNonStopWord(int[] nums, int value)
    {

    }
    public String search( String [] Strings , String july) {
        String [] skoal = {"THE", "BE", "TO", "OF", "AND", "A", "IN",
                "THAT", "I", "IT", "ON", "IN", "BUT", "IS", "WITH"};
        for ( String i = 0, ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String zach = ("Amazon offered up more answers Thursday about what"
                + " caused a bunch of websites to fail two days ago. According "
                + "to a postmortem by the company's cloud services business, "
                + "around 9:37 a.m. PT Tuesday an Amazon worker incorrectly"
                + " punched in a command while trying to debug an issue. "
                + "That command shut down a large set of servers at Amazon Web "
                + "Services' Northern Virginia site, causing a domino effect of"
                + " problems. Other services that relied on those S3 cloud"
                + " storage servers were disrupted. Also, removing so much "
                + "server capacity required a full system restart, which then "
                + "took longer than expected, AWS said. The sites affected "
                + "included Quora, Imgur, IFTTT, Giphy and Slack. Amazon was "
                + "able to fix the issue by about 2 p.m. PT.");
        zach = zach.replace(",","");
        zach = zach.replace(".","");
        zach = zach.toUpperCase();
        String [] strings = zach.split(" ");
        for (String s1: strings) 
        {
                System.out.println(s1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the "stop words"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i want to return false next to them and true next to everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would there be anything wrong with using [String#matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) here:

```
public boolean hasWord(String input, String word) {
    return input.matches(".*\\b" + word + "\\b.*"));
}

// now call the above method from somewhere
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String [] skoal = {"THE", "BE", "TO", "OF", "AND", "A", "IN",
                       "THAT", "I", "IT", "ON", "IN", "BUT", "IS", "WITH"};
    String zach = "...";           // your original content
    zach = zach.replace(",", "");  // remove punctuation
    zach = zach.replace(".", "");
    zach = zach.toUpperCase();     // uppercase

    for (String stop : skoal) {
        if (hasWord(stop)) {
            System.out.println(word + " true");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(word + " false");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need the is nonStopWord method to find the words and return true or false and then i need to call upon that method in main

Comment: I don't understand the signature of `isNonStopWord()`.  What do integers have to do with searching your text?

Comment: the signature is wrong I am not sure how to write the boolean correctly

Comment: @elliott yes that function works in my main but i need to use that in the IsNonStopWord and call upon it in main and I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you might use [`Stream.noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) like

```
String[] strings = zach.split("\\s+");
for (String s1 : strings) {
    System.out.println(s1 + ": " 
            + Stream.of(skoal).noneMatch(s -> s.equals(s1)));
}
```

And, `\\s+` matches one (or more) whitespace in the *regular expression*.